# Xscope similar tool for Windows

Tags: windows, visual-design

Xscope is a great tool for measuring, creating guides, checking color; it also has a feature to send what you are seeing in a window to Xscope for iOS, so you can preview your designs on your phone.

I really need something similar for Windows.

Comment: Can you provide the readers here a brief explanation of what Xscope does?

Comment: Ready I jus edited my description

Comment: 2 years and no answer!!! Argh. Why does my company use Windows. :/ xScope is like a toolbox that God accidentally lost and you somehow found it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer of windows alternative for xScope. You can try it http://rulerforwindows.com for free.

Current features

- Create, layout and adjust custom marker boxes that float on top of all other on-screen elements.
- Quickly and easily find the spacing between any point visible on the screen.
- Magnify the area under your mouse preview color and the cross under mouse position.
- Display vertical and horizontal guides that float on top of all else on the screen for easy alignment.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As you see, all well-received answers here are [more than just a link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232). Please consider [edit]ing your answer and add more information about the software, especially how it meets the requirements in the question.